# Prometheus where/if clause

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have query I want to run only on hosts with a certain service running

the pseudo code would look something like

```
windows_os_virtual_memory_bytes 
where
windows_service_state{name="sense",state="running"} == 1
```

So that I only get the virtual memory if the service with `name="sense"` is active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the on clause to match labels. In this case,

```
windows_os_virtual_memory_bytes > 0 and  on(instance) (windows_service_state{name="sense",state="running"} == 1)
```

So that both conditions must be met (`and`) where `instance` matches. You can use a vector of labels in the `on()` function.

https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#one-to-one-vector-matches